# Set Interval in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a google chrome extension that gives the user a new word everyday. This word appears in the popup and is inserted into an array so they can study them later. In my background.js I have the classic setInterval, like below:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
...code to get new word and push to array
}, (12*3600000));
```

The problem however is that this functions works on every tab open! So I left it for a day with 10 tabs open and I had 10 new words. How can I have a function within a google chrome extension that only runs once a day, independent of how many tabs are open? Should this function live in another page? The only other js pages I have are popup.js and options.js and I believe those only run when popup.html and options.html are open. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the chrome.alarm api? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms

Comment: How did I miss this!? Should work perfectly, thanks!

Comment: while alsrms work, its *not* true thst a setInterval inside a background page would run per open page. a single setInterval at extension load time works fine too.