# setInterval in Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

I have created a JS countdown timer that works well on it's own. However, I wanted to make it into a chrome extension to make it a little more convenient but I seem to be having trouble making `setInterval` work inside the extension. Is this a limitation of Chrome extensions or is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094918/set-interval-in-google-chrome-extension

Comment: @Mörre I have seen this but it does not address my issue.